# How to shuffle the training data in Keras for an Autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using an autoencoder in Keras. I'm looking to shuffle the training data `x_train` so that the autoencoder will reconstruct the data to a different sample from the same class. Is this possible?

```
model_train = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=1000,
          shuffle=True,
          callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stopping],
          validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

I assume that `shuffle=True` is shuffling `x_train` and calculating the loss based on the *same* pairs, and that's not what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but Keras won't do it for you as it shuffles the data and labels together. Assuming you've got the labels, I found this function quite useful for your purposes:

```
import numpy as np

def create_pairs(data, labels):
    # Exclude batch dimension
    pairs = np.empty(0, 2, *data.shape[1:])

    for label in np.unique(labels):
        idxs = np.where(labels == label)[0]
        # Indexes must be even in order to create pairs
        idxs = idxs if len(idxs) % 2 == 0 else idxs[:-1]
        np.random.shuffle(idxs)

        samples = data[idxs].reshape((-1, 2, *data.shape[1:]))
        pairs = np.vstack((pairs, samples))
    return pairs[:, 0], pairs[:, 1]
```

Now that the data is shuffled and divided into pairs you can train your model:

```
x_train, y_train = create_pairs(data, labels)
history = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=1000,
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stopping],
    validation_split=0.2)
```